# БД на хостинге

Tags: база-данных, хостинг

Когда  хостинг покупаешь, как там дела с БД?
мне  надо переслать коды таблиц?
или как?

```
   CREATE TABLE  `best`.`name` (
   `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
   `name` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ......
```

Ди и как там с phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно на странице провайдера все подробно расписано.

Апдейт: естественно, вам придется самому позаботится о структуре. **phpMyAdmin** обычно тоже в наличии.